# Cell content is cut off (vertically) when making boldface = because no longer completely top-aligned

Tags: microsoft-excel, sharepoint

> This is when viewing the Excel inside the desktop browser version of
> Microsoft SharePoint. Not when opening inside the Excel software itself.

The following concerns a cell of which the content is cut off (vertically) when making the content boldface. This seems to be because there is no way to have it **completely** top-aligned (after making the text boldface, it seems to shift down a bit):

[image]

I tried to debug it with everything described in this support article https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/fix-data-that-is-cut-off-in-cells-e996e213-6514-49d8-b82a-2721cef6144e but nothing worked.

What would be the most elegant workaround to prevent this please? I don't want to change the font-size.

Comment: change the row height.  With BOLD option on, set the row height so everything looks good.  That way it will work for when both bold and no bold text

Comment: That's what I do now, but this still makes it look quite ugly. It doesn't make it top-aligned.

Comment: have you used the alignment setting for the cell so it aligns vertically from the top?

Comment: @ForwardEd Yes, very definitely.

Comment: In order for other to reproduce the situation and "play with it" to look at options, you may want to consider adding row height, font size, font and any other cell & text setting that might be active, so they can reproduce the problem.  When I try with my default settings I am not getting any issue.

Comment: This is when viewing the Excel inside the desktop browser version of Microsoft SharePoint. Not when opening inside the Excel software itself.